Does anyone have this paragraph from the Be'er HaGolah in English or Spanish?
Does anyone have the Be'er HaGolah on Shulchan Arukh in English or Spanish? Only looking for the paragraph below:
Be'er HaGolah on Shulchan Arukh, Choshen Mishpat 348
ה) וכ"כ הרמב"ם בפי"א מה' גזילה ד"ד שהי' כאבידתו ומותר' וביאר שם כיצד כגון שעשה העכו"ם חשבון וטעה צריך שיאמר לו ישראל ראה שעל חשבונך אני סימך וכו' ע"כ וכתב ה"ה פסק כרב כהנא שם דעביד הכין וע"ל ר"ס רס"ו ושאם החזיר האבידה לעכו"ם לקדש את השם כדי שיפארו את ישראל וידעו שהם בעלי אמונה ה"ז משובח וכו' ע"כ וכן הדין בחזר' הטעות שטעה העכו"ם מעצמו ואני כותב זאת לדורות שראיתי רבים גדלו והעשירו מן טעות שהטעו העכו"ם ולא הצליחו וירדו נכסיה' לטמיון ולא הניחו אחריהם ברכה וכמ"ש בספר חסידים סימן תתרע"ד רבים אשר קדשו ה' והחזירו טעיו' העכו"ם בדבר חשוב גדלו והעשירו והצליחו והניחו יתרם לעולליה'

Hey, Yerushalma, welcome to the site! Would a translation of the paragraph by someone on site suffice?

Thank you! And yes, that would be just great.

This is a direct translation, to the best of my ability:


And this is like the Rambam wrote, in the eleventh perek of Hilchos Gezeila, in the fourth paragraph (I.e. halacha); that they (mistakes made by a non-Jew) are like their lost objects and are permitted. And he further explained there (in the next halacha): "How so? For example, if a non-Jew made a mistake in his calculations, the Jew must tell him 'see that I am reliant on your calculations'..." (The Rambam goes on to say that the Jew should say that he doesn't know what the correct amount is and is reliant on the non-Jew's math, at this point if the non-Jew made a mistake the Jew can benefit). And Harav Hamagid (the Magid Mishna) wrote there "the Rambam paskened like Rav Kahana there (in Perek Hagozel U'Ma'achil), who acted in this way." And look back to the beginning of siman 266: "if one returns a lost objects to a non-Jew to sanctify God's name so that Jews will be praised and will be known for being trustworthy, this is praiseworthy..." And the same is true in regards to returning a mistake that the non-Jew himself made. And I write this for future generations, as I have seen many who have become great and wealthy from causing a non-Jew to make a mistake, and they were not succesful and they lost all their wealth, and they didn't leave a blessing behind (for their heirs when they died). And this is as is written in Sefer chasidim siman 1074: "many who sanctified God's name, and returned non-Jew's mistakes when it was something important, became great and wealthy and succeeded, and left their excess to their kids"


Anything in parentheses is my own addition to make the translation clearer.

Wow, thank you so much! Beautifully translated and I realize it's a complex text. Thanks for the clarifying comments in parenthesis as well. This is so deeply appreciated.
